# How to access the Laravel Direct Path

Tags: php, laravel

Am new to laravel, I have install laravel using composer in my linux server, the problem is I couldn't able to access the domainname.com but domainname.com/public/ then only I can able to access the page. Kindly suggest me how to access the site with domainname.com/ instead of domainname.com/public/

Am running in shared hosting so there multiple domain name with folders are available as well.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have direct access to your machine? (via ssh)

Comment: @lukasgeiter : yes, am having SSH Access

Comment: Alright. Then you can either create/edit a virtual host (see gmarintes answer) or you can change your document root in the httpd.conf file. It kinda depends on how your set up is.

Comment: In your apache2 directory (normally at /etc/apache2), do you have the folder "sites-available"? And in there do you have a file? (probably with your domainname as filename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that your rewrite module is enabled. In your case, share hosting providers often enable it for you.

Second, create an `.htaccess` file in your home folder (the folder contains `artisan` file) with this content.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
# For all files not found in the file system, reroute the request to the
# "index.php" front controller, keeping the query string intact
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond $1 !^(public)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to sort out the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a <VirtualHost> in your Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/laravel/public
    ServerName your.domain.com

    <Directory /path/to/your/laravel/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All

        Options FollowSymLinks

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can access your Laravel site as:
    http://your.domain.com/

Comment: Hope this may not be suitable for shared hosting.